# Why can't I get XCode 4 to work with GitHub?

Tags: git, github, xcode4

I am still learning to program, and I am completely new to Git, so I am sure this is just me doing something wrong...

I have set up an account on GitHub, and muddled my way through their instructions to the point where I now have a copy of my (existing) project on my repository. I have then tested this by cloning the repository from within XCode 4, and this cloned version works fine.

But the "source control" submenu is all greyed out, and I can't add my cloned version as a "working copy" because "its repository could not be located". So there are no options to commit anything back to the repository after I have made changes.

I think I must just be misunderstanding some basic concepts here but a day of googling has not helped... I'd really appreciate any guidance!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one route worth trying would be to create a new project within Xcode, and check the box that says "Create local Git repository." Then follow github's instructions on how to add itself as a remote and go from there.

I have been using several GitHub projects with no problems, perhaps you have something set up wrong with git, the project or github. It is rather difficult to diagnose without playing around with it.